# what is most concise way to transfer variables to python string.format?

Tags: python

For example:

```
def print_template(a,b):
   c="the c"
   template="{a} {b} {c}"
   print template.format(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

it is working, but the parameter list of the format function is a bit verbose. is there anyway to make it more concise? perhaps by passing all the local variables to the format function?

Comment: local variables may include other objects, functions and stuff. You sure you want to print all locals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* pass local variables, if you wish:

```
def print_template(a,b):
    c="the c"
    template="{a} {b} {c}"
    print template.format(**vars())
```

Demo:

```
>>> print_template(1,2)
1 2 the c
```